# Yogic Theory of Intelligence for AI

Tags: scripture, philosophy, belief, mind, nyaya-sutra

What are some yogic texts which discuss the precise, scientific nature of the components of the mind and how the human intelligence operates in great detail? I am aware of the *Nyaya Sutras*, but I was wondering if there are any others which could be of particular value in designing an artificial intelligence system.

Comment: from my experience this will not help much in creation of AI.

Comment: You never know. Many thinkers in AI say progress is contingent upon a new, improved theory intelligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get a bigger understanding of Intelligence before Humans as well. You need a broader theoretical understanding of intelligence before specific lab specimen intelligence - like humans. Correct. AI has to be more General. So, you can specialize it for Humans. These are books about the knowledge of Cosmic Intelligence that also operates Humans & Sadhguru (Say when you sleep, & the computer your AI runs is turned off or say a Lightning strikes it :-)).

1. Kundalini Yoga Tattwa Maha Rahasya ( Paranjyothi Gnyana Guru Rukkumani Ammayar) - Tamil print ( English name is Paranjyothi Mahan's Secrets of Thavam & Philosophy of Kundalini Yoga) - Malaysian print. 03-4296 7950 Mobile : 017-377 9367. Cosmic Kundalini Yoga Meditation Group. - Very good if you can read Tamil.
2. The Serpent Power - the secrets of Tantric & Shakti Yoga - Arthur Avalon(Sir John Woodroffe)- Very good one.
3. Spanda-Karika - Kashmiri Saivism book 2.
4. Para Trisaka Vivarana Kashmiri Saivism book 3.

Post more questions after!

Comment: Thank you for answering! These books seem to discuss kundalini yoga and the subtle astral body (chakra, pranic currents) in great detail. I am looking for books strictly on the mind and the intellect. For example, one which covers all of the functions of the mind (imagination, will, discrimination, intellect, etc.) in great detail.

Comment: & where do you think your will comes from, or your imagination? Or your thoughts? Have you heard of Panchakosha?  What exactly biologically is intelligence? Are you a biologist? Or a Neuroscientist?  Have you read the western books? Nick Bostrom’s super intelligence for e.g? Roger Penrose’s Pan psychism theory? 
Do you want to approach the Intelligence Top Down or Bottom up? Have you studied Bacterial gravitating towards Sugar? What minimal intelligence does it have? Your question is very general & hence I have the most general books available? You think a neural network solves all problems?

Comment: Everything ultimately comes from the Source. I am a biologist with an interest in developing artificial general intelligence. The Western books you suggest seem quite interesting and I will give them a read, even though my preferences are Oriental. Is there an Indian text strictly dedicated to the components and functions of the intellect sheath (of the Panchakosha)?

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close Your question.

Why? Because AI equals to **control.**

There is no need to AI to understand Yogic texts with the mind, if not connected with a heart.

My suggestion would be to study the texts before finding a subtle way to make money with them.

Comment: Artificial intelligence will play a vital role in the spiritual evolution of mankind, as everything we can accomplish with our intellects will be worthless, leaving us to contemplate deeper spiritual questions and meditate. Read what Sadhguru has to say about AI: https://isha.sadhguru.org/us/en/wisdom/article/artificial-intelligence-growth-mean-humanity My intentions were to facilitate this, not to make money.

Comment: lol, i don't need to read Sadhguru! Artificial Intelligence is a fake crap that will just render our lives a nightmare!!